# Creating timed word game in Java

Tags: java

I have been trying out how to create a game (in Java) in which the player needs to unscramble a word in 4 seconds.

If the answer is right, the game continues. If it is wrong the game ends and the player is presented with their final score (1pt per right answer).

I am struggling to keep track of points. Every time it loops back through, points reset itself. Also, the game continues if any answer at all is entered.

My code is a trainwreck and I might need to start over, but I was hoping I could be pointed in the right direction.

I am new here so please let me know about any formatting or any issues with my question or even where to go to get better assistance. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class test {

    private String ans = "";

    keepScore Score = new keepScore();
    int scoree = 0;

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            if (ans.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time's up!", "",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Score.keepScore(scoree),
                        "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    };

    public void getInput() throws Exception {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        dictionaryClass object = new dictionaryClass();

        timer.schedule(task, 4 * 1000);

        String word = "0";

        String a = "";
        int x = 0;
        randomLetters meth = new randomLetters();
        int randomSequence = meth.randomLetters(x);

        if (randomSequence == 1) {
            word = "1";
            ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("f s h i");
            if (ans.equals(object.dictionaryClass(word))) {
                scoree = Score.keepScore(scoree);
                System.out.println("ok: " + scoree);

            }
        }

        if (randomSequence == 2) {
            word = "2";
            ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("k p n i");
            if (ans.equals(object.dictionaryClass(word))) {
                scoree = Score.keepScore(scoree + 1);

            }
        }

        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("you have entered: " + ans);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // int forever=1;
        int count = 0;
        int points = 0;

        for (int aa = 0; aa < 10; aa++) {
            try {
                (new test()).getInput();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("");

            count = count + 1;
            System.out.println("count:" + count);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Score: " + count, "Score",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You need to solve it one problem at a time. How about doing it without a timer first? I guess it will be easier to test your logic that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Futures` and and `ExecutorService` with a timeout instead of a `TimerTask`.

You use the `ExecutorService` to run your input dialog in one Thread and the main thread waits until the dialog returns or a timeout occurs.

It could be implemented this way

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WordGame {

    private static final int IDX_SCRUMBLED = 0;
    private static final int IDX_UNSCRUMBLED = 1;

    private static final  List<String[]> DICT;
    static {
        // TODO: think of the correct data structure
        List<String[]> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        // list contains the scumbled word followed by the unscumbled word.
        tmp.add( new String[]{"k p n i", "pink" });
        tmp.add(new String[]{"f s h i", "fish" });
        DICT = Collections.unmodifiableList(tmp);
    }

    public WordGame() {
        random = new Random();
        fetchInputExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    private final ExecutorService fetchInputExecutor;

    private final Random random;




    private int getNextNotNegativeRandomInt(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        int value = -1;
        if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0 || startIndex > endIndex 
                || endIndex > Integer.MAX_VALUE -1) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid bounds " + startIndex + " " + endIndex);
        do {
            value = random.nextInt(endIndex + 1);
        } while (value < startIndex || value > endIndex);
        return value;
    }

    public String fetchInput(final String scrumbled) 
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {



        Future<String> future = fetchInputExecutor.submit(new Callable<String>() {

            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(scrumbled);
            }

        });

        // wait 4 seconds 
        return future.get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    }

    public int playRound(int oldScore) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        try {
            int idx = getNextNotNegativeRandomInt(0, DICT.size()-1);
            String answer = fetchInput(DICT.get(idx)[IDX_SCRUMBLED]);
            if (DICT.get(idx)[IDX_UNSCRUMBLED].equals(answer)) {
                return oldScore + 1;
            } 
            return oldScore;

        } catch (TimeoutException toe) {
            JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time's up!", "",
                     JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
             return oldScore;
        }
    }

    public int play() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int score = 0;

        for (int aa = 0; aa < 10; aa++) {
            score = playRound(score);
        }
        return score;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int score = new WordGame().play();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Score: " + score, "Score",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```

It can also be implemented using a `Timer` and `TimerTask`
Here the TimerTask kills the DialogMessageBox after the timeout value is reached.

the `playRound` and `fetchInput` may look something like:

```
public String fetchInput(final String scrumbled)  {
       // we need something that prevents the timeup dialog if the answer was 
       // entered within the timeout value.
       // because we access it from two threads let's us a AtomicBoolean
       final AtomicBoolean completed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

       // start a Timer which kills the OptionPane after a specified delay.
       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

          @Override
          public void run() {

            if (!completed.get())
                JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();

          }

       }, 4 * 1000L);

       String tmp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(scrumbled); 
       // prevent killing one of the next Input Dialogs
       completed.set(true);


       return tmp;
}

public int playRound(int oldScore) {
        int idx = getNextNotNegativeRandomInt(0, DICT.size()-1);
        String answer = fetchInput(DICT.get(idx)[IDX_SCRUMBLED]);

       // if the dialog was disposed because of an timeout the result will be null 
       if (answer == null) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time's up!", "",
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           return oldScore;

       }

        if (DICT.get(idx)[IDX_UNSCRUMBLED].equals(answer)) {
            return oldScore + 1;
        } 
        return oldScore;
}
```